# cannot make ubuntu autostart my script

Tags: scripts, kde, autostart, xinput

I need to force my KDE Plasma installed on ubuntu 18.04 to run the following script on startup (after login):

```
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Finger touch" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen stylus" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen eraser" eDP-1-1
```

So I've put it in

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
crontab -e
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
maybe some other places that I forgot
```

I've also created a *.sh with these 3 lines and put it in the settings->autostart in the "desktop file" section and in the "script file" section. In the latter one I put it twice: under "startup" option and under "before session start-up" option. I put it in the settings->login screen (sddm) "advanced" tab -> commands -> "reboot command" section. I have also tried to create a *.desktop file in 'cd ~/.config/autostart/' and put the following content in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec="/usr/bin/xinput_autostart.sh"
Name=Xinput
```

I put it with and without the "root" and "sudo" prescriptions, I put it everywhere I could where I could only find on the internet and it does not work. But when I execute exactly the same lines in the terminal manually or if I simply double click the *.sh file then it works!!! I am out of ideas, please help!

Comment: This might be better as a systemd service, this answer goes in how to set that up. But I think your script "/usr/bin/xinput_autostart.sh" may be the problem. Make sure it has a shebang at the top, e.g. `#!/bin/sh`. And make sure to make it executable, something like `sudo chmod 660` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: I have this line in the beginning of the script, if fact I've tried both  "#!/bin/sh" and "#!/bin/bash", dunno the difference tho, just seen them somewhere. And ye the script was set to be executable with "chmod" command, if I now simple double click it it will be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put shell scripts in:

```
~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/
```

<sup>(these will execute at login before launching Plasma, make sure they have execute bit and ends with *.sh)</sup>

Comment: I will try this, but I think I have explained it in a wrong way - I need the script to be executed after I login to plasma, not before. In fact, before I login, on the sddm login screen my touchscreen mapped correctly, it is mismapped after I login, so thats why I need to remap the xinput after I login to plasma.

Comment: [Autostart directories recognized by plasma](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-desktop/blob/b368bd1b04b4013b18e400666d0bc79b6c4b30f0/kcms/autostart/autostart.cpp#L134)

Comment: try redirecting output to a log file: `xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Finger touch" eDP-1-1 > ~/wacom.log 2>&1` this redirect any messages to wacom.log in your home directory.

Comment: As it turned out I already had the script in the '~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/'. As I mentioned I forgot some of the places I had put it in.
I have also put it in the "~/.config/autostart-scripts" and I have added the " > ~/wacom.log 2>&1" Now there is an empty wacom.log file in my home directory indeed. So does it mean that the script is executed? But I still experience the xinput mapping mismatch, does it mean that the script is executed but the xinput settings are overwritten afterwards once again? Any idea I can track this somehow?

Comment: Yes, I double checked it, it seems that the script is executed (wacom.log is created) but the xinput settings being rewritten afterwards... Maybe I can add sort of 'wait x seconds' function into the script to fix the issue, is there such a command?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @bac0n in helping me tracking the issue. As it turned out, the script was executed all along, but due to some reason, default xinput settings were overwriting it every time on startup. The solution might be not the most elegant, but it is the only solution I was able to come up with and it works for me:

```
sleep 1; xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Finger touch" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen stylus" eDP-1-1
xinput --map-to-output "Wacom HID 48DE Pen eraser" eDP-1-1
```

Comment: i was about to suggest that :)=